# Change the size of circle selection without mouse scroll

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools

[image]

I'm talking about this circle selection tool that can be accessed by pressing <kbd>C</kbd>.

I know one can change its size with mouse scroll with holding <kbd>LMB</kbd>. But I only use stylus and one of its button is <kbd>RMB</kbd> and another is <kbd>MMB</kbd>. So I don't have a mouse scroll and both <kbd>RMB</kbd> and <kbd>MMB</kbd> are rather useful for Blender and I have no customizable button left. How can I adjust the size of circle selection tool?

Comment: Hey :). *Numpad +* and *Numpad -* work too.

Comment: _PgUp_ and _PgDn_ work as well.